# Change a regular Bitbucket branch to a release branch?

Tags: bitbucket

We have a project that is really going to be it's own release but when we initially created a branch for it, it was just created as a regular branch, not a release branch. It also doesn't seem to be set up as a feature, bug fix, or hotfix branch, just a plain branch.  Is there any way to change the branch type so that it is a release branch?

Comment: Can't you just merge it with a new release branch?

Comment: @TonyStark, yeah, I thought about that, but I just thought if there was a way to just make it a release branch or move it into the release folder that that would be "cleaner."

Comment: @TonyStark, if I do create a new release branch and merge it, can I remove the original branch without it effecting anything, or does that branch need to stick around?

Comment: Bitbucket is "just" git so a "release" branch is just a branch. You can remove the original branch after merging.